# Windows Attrib - How to made ALL files on a drive read/write - visible

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I have a drive with some hidden, some readonly files.. how can I make ALL the files in ALL directories - visible and read/write using the `attrib` command or windows 10 comannds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
attrib /s /d -s -h -r d:\*.*
```

should accomplish that task. `d:\` being the start directory.

The /d should process directories in addition to files.

Comment: I have a documents setting folder that is still not visible. Any ideas?  thx